# NPN Transistor calculation

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, npn

[image: 1]

I want to find the value for \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$. Is my calculation right? Assume \$h_{fe} = 120\$, \$V_{ce} = 25\$.

Comment: No, your calculations are incorrect.  The voltage across R2 is Vbe1. And the voltage across R1 is Vcc - (Vbe2 + Vbe1) = Vcc - 2Vbe.

Comment: Is the schematic an attempt to design a constant current source for Leds? If so why you consider Vce = 25V? It should be about 35V.

Comment: @ G36. So, R2 = Vbe/IR2 ; R1=(Vcc-2Vbe)/IR1. IR2 = 3.78mA and IR1 = 7.5mA?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Yes to design constant current source. Vce = 25V because I refer to datasheet since used S8050 transistor. How did you get 35V?

Comment: @Kim Since the Vcc is 48v minus 6v minus 6v minus 0.6v on R2 is about 35V on CE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to choose a transistors with higher Vce rating (like 60V) to be in spec.

**Calculations:**

Considering Vbe of Q1 and Q2 = 0.6V, then
R2 = Vbe_Q1 / Ic = 0.6 / 0.0075 = 80 ohm
and,
R1 = (Vcc - VbeQ2 - VR2) / IR1 = (48 - 0.6 - 0.6) / 0.0015 =  31.2 kohm

**Note:**
*Btw, you can choose IR1 less than yours 1.5mA (like 500uA or so) since it should be enough for such a small Ic (7.5mA).

Then R1 is 93.6 kohm.*

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you